# Plaid OAuth redirect flow in desktop web application

Tags: plaid

I want to implement the redirect flow to support OAuth in Plaid.
When I test it in the sandbox environment, using the Platypus OAuth Bank test bank, it always opens it as a popup instead of a redirect.
I also tried to set a Webview user-agent as described in Plaid docs, but still no redirect... (Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; SM-G960F Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/95.0.4638.50 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.2254.59405)
What am I missing?

Also, as I understand that the redirect flow is not relevant for desktop web, so if we have only a desktop web application(some kind of an admin dashboard), do I need to implement the redirect flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is only for desktop web, you do not need to implement the redirect flow.