# Testing Plaid OAuth redirect flow

Tags: plaid

I am trying to test Plaid's OAuth redirect flow, and I always get a popup.

Someone else just asked the same question, [Plaid OAuth redirect flow in desktop web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598594/plaid-oauth-redirect-flow-in-desktop-web-application) But they also asked if needed it since they were desktop only. We are web only, but we want to work nicely on mobile as well.
Keep in mind, I am testing this on the desktop. But was under the impression that I can test the redirect code on the desktop.

I found one piece of documentation that says the sandbox will always use the redirect flow if you specify a redirect, and another that says you have to use a special user agent.
I am specifying a redirect. The redirect is set on the dashboard. And I've created a new user agent (copied the one in the documentation:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; SM-G960F Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/95.0.4638.50 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.2254.59405
```

The link request looks like:

```
 'auth': {'auth_type_select_enabled': False,
          'automated_microdeposits_enabled': True,
          'same_day_microdeposits_enabled': False},
 'client_name': 'Our Name',
 'country_codes': ['US'],
 'language': 'en',
 'products': ['auth', 'identity'],
 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3000/account/bank-finalize',
 'user': {'client_user_id': 'our-id'},
 'webhook': 'https://webhook'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this behavior was recently changed in Sandbox and there is not currently a way to test this flow in the Sandbox environment -- I'd instead recommend testing this in the Development environment with any institution that supports OAuth flows (you can find a list by using `/institutions/get`, but some major ones include Bank of America, Wells Fargo, Capital One, and Chase).